# Is there a way to search in Oracle using a string if you don't know if the string is a schema/table/etc..?

Tags: sql, oracle, data-dictionary

I'm trying to search for something particular in the Oracle database, but I don't know if it is a table, or schema, or user, etc...

Is there any command that allows to make a search for string if its type is unknown?

For example:
SQL> SHOW STRING 'the_string'

Comment: You may get an exact answer here, but may we ask how you ended up in this situation?  I mean, a user is a very different thing than a table.

Comment: You could search every column of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = @value OR TABLE_NAME = @value OR COLUMN_NAME = @value`

Comment: That won't work in Oracle, @Dai. But yes, the idea is OK - for tables and columns. The main problem is in Phillip's "etc", because it seems that the "search object" can be virtually *anything*. From my point of view, the question itself is meaningless, but hey - what do I know?

Comment: Assume that a user has asked to grab something from "OBJECT" but they weren't specific on what "OBJECT" even was. I'm just tired of asking the users to be specific in a followup email. That is the situation.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select * from all_objects where object_name like '%your object name%'
```

Please note also,

- ALL_OBJECTS describes all objects accessible to the current user.
- DBA_OBJECTS describes all objects in the database.

You would need the proper access rights assigned to your user.

Comment: If `%your object name%` is lower case characters, , that works; but object names are usually UPPER CASE so you may want to `select * from all_objects where lower(object_name) like '%your object name%';`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a unified query that should help:

```
SELECT 'User/Schema' match_type,
        username
FROM dba_users -- if you have access to dba_users uses all_users instead
WHERE UPPER(username) LIKE '%THE_STRING%'
UNION
SELECT object_type,
       owner || '.' || object_name object_name
FROM dba_objects  -- or all_objects if no access to dba_objects
WHERE UPPER ( owner || '.' || object_name ) LIKE '%THE_STRING%'
ORDER BY 1, 2
/
```

Note, the `dba_` views will show everything (that matches), the `all_` views will only show matches for objects that you have access to.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to OldProgrammer's answer, if that query returns no information, to find if the name is a user ID (which is basically synonymous with schemas), you need to query `ALL_USERS` or `DBA_USERS`:

```
select username from all_users where lower(username) like '%your_name_to_find%';
```